# Write message from SQS to database using Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

Im working on a project with AWS, and I've created  an endpoint that I've connected to and SQS queue that then triggers a Lambda function. The Lambda should write data to a database but for some reason it doesn't. When I try to trigger it manually with a request like this

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "messageId": "11d6ee51-4cc7-4302-9e22-7cd8afdaadf5",
      "receiptHandle": "AQEBBX8nesZEXmkhsmZeyIE8iQAMig7qw...",
      "body": {
        "duration": "1230",
        "player_1": "UR-da336be50ba9b8e53b8",
        "player_2": "UR-a67322a021284404128",
        "status_1": 1,
        "status_2": 0
      },
      "attributes": {
        "ApproximateReceiveCount": "1",
        "SentTimestamp": "1573251510774",
        "SequenceNumber": "18849496460467696128",
        "MessageGroupId": "1",
        "SenderId": "AIDAIO23YVJENQZJOL4VO",
        "MessageDeduplicationId": "1",
        "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1573251510774"
      },
      "messageAttributes": {},
      "md5OfBody": "e4e68fb7bd0e697a0ae8f1bb342846b3",
      "eventSource": "aws:sqs",
      "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-2:123456789012:fifo.fifo",
      "awsRegion": "us-east-2"
    },
    {
      "messageId": "11d6ee51-4cc7-4302-9e22-7cd8afdaadf5",
      "receiptHandle": "AQEBBX8nesZEXmkhsmZeyIE8iQAMig7qw...",
      "body": {
        "duration": "5510",
        "player_1": "UR-da336be50ba9b8e53b8",
        "player_2": "UR-a67322a021284404128",
        "status_1": 1,
        "status_2": 0
      },
      "attributes": {
        "ApproximateReceiveCount": "1",
        "SentTimestamp": "1573251510774",
        "SequenceNumber": "18849496460467696128",
        "MessageGroupId": "1",
        "SenderId": "AIDAIO23YVJENQZJOL4VO",
        "MessageDeduplicationId": "1",
        "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1573251510774"
      },
      "messageAttributes": {},
      "md5OfBody": "e4e68fb7bd0e697a0ae8f1bb342846b3",
      "eventSource": "aws:sqs",
      "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-2:123456789012:fifo.fifo",
      "awsRegion": "us-east-2"
    }
  ]
}
```

It works fine, but when it get called from SQS nothing happens and it deletes the message from SQS.

The code for my Lambda:

```
const { Client } = require("pg");

const client = new Client({
  user: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
  host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
  database: process.env.POSTGRES_DATABASE,
  password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
  port: parseInt(process.env.POSTGRES_PORT),
});

client.connect();

async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    await callback(array[index], index, array);
  }
}

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  try {
    await asyncForEach(event.Records, async (record) => {
      //Writes the game info to the DB
    const result = await client.query(
      `INSERT INTO game_data (duration) VALUES (
        ${record.body.duration}
        ) RETURNING game_id`
    );

    const res = await Promise.all([
      client.query(
        `INSERT INTO player_game_data (user_id,game_id,player_game_status) VALUES (
            '${record.body.player_1}',
            '${result.rows[0].game_id}',
             ${record.body.status_1}
            )`
      ),
      client.query(
        `INSERT INTO player_game_data (user_id,game_id,player_game_status) VALUES (
            '${record.body.player_2}',
            '${result.rows[0].game_id}',
             ${record.body.status_2}
            )`
      ),
    ]);
  }
  );
  return{
    statusCode: 200}
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      statusCode: 400,
      error: error.message,
    };
  }
};
```

I've tested the queue and it works fine so the problem is probably somewhere here..

Comment: Please share logs.

Comment: Where can i find them?

Comment: Cloudwatch logs

Comment: First you have to write them, using `console.log()`. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-logging.html

Comment: I managed to fix it by myself. Thanks for that though. I was wondering how it's done.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the JSON you send to SQS gets converted to a string so you need to convert it back to a JSON in your Lambda using JSON.parse().

The request that comes through SQS looks something like this:

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "messageId": "bc62a976-06ef-4727-8bb5-8d7b0a474f7d",
      "receiptHandle": "AQEBd4oxuMTytPn8AWORy992aGqGO5By+pM1x2dtZpyn0n8cxTJEd9/BXemUnAAbU+tx1jRlsRWCYhPnrrBvCj91nUpw5gT10WGkuQcv6fCH+ePqqON6sIHy9+8csqhzCwphDqdA23SLfidEGMwuW8mvNN+Lh541vfgHoYSQhMv51qLjHADbiSUzfsIYVnvmqU+C3D55OX/OhDOJoWY87XIEjpSEqRKx4s8wTF6edpYyun0IBYUA68W5CFkg+RBuWPeKsGLNENCvCpawcknYOCKrxeMrWRTh73qHZzH6QnNTO5S4fzQONKH2MWjFsIy7T01w1feNSD3qt/m3vakWhQnhi8VDn9KUJCIdKbhxpdqZB3QSPAKvfjRtEkwXQu2pGUpezMtWbNmsQfaEw84+7BV/CQ==",
      "body": "{\r\n    \"duration\": \"69\",\r\n    \"player_1\": \"UR-da336be50ba9b8e53b8\",\r\n    \"player_2\": \"UR-a67322a021284404128\",\r\n    \"status_1\": 0,\r\n    \"status_2\": 1\r\n}",
      "attributes": {
        "ApproximateReceiveCount": "1",
        "AWSTraceHeader": "Root=1-5f454d30-8772a1ac004584ac5e0cbf48",
        "SentTimestamp": "1598377264745",
        "SenderId": "AROAYLJPJR5FJH6OQCRDF:BackplaneAssumeRoleSession",
        "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1598377264750"
      },
      "messageAttributes": {},
      "md5OfBody": "0be85f29f6c6dd29e328b58a01e3db2a",
      "eventSource": "aws:sqs",
      "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:574014197578:dev-Post-GameResults",
      "awsRegion": "us-east-1"
    }
  ]
}
```

After I parsed the body everything worked as intended..

Code after edit:

```
const { Client } = require("pg");

const client = new Client({
  user: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
  host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
  database: process.env.POSTGRES_DATABASE,
  password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
  port: parseInt(process.env.POSTGRES_PORT),
});

client.connect();

async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    await callback(array[index], index, array);
  }
}

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  try {
      await asyncForEach(event.Records, async (record) => {
        var body = JSON.parse(record.body);
      //Writes the game info to the DB
    const result = await client.query(
      `INSERT INTO game_data (duration) VALUES (${body.duration}) RETURNING game_id`
    );

    const res = await Promise.all([
      client.query(
        `INSERT INTO player_game_data (user_id,game_id,player_game_status) VALUES (
            '${body.player_1}',
            '${result.rows[0].game_id}',
             ${body.status_1}
            )`
      ),
      client.query(
        `INSERT INTO player_game_data (user_id,game_id,player_game_status) VALUES (
            '${body.player_2}',
            '${result.rows[0].game_id}',
             ${body.status_2}
            )`
      ),
    ]);
    }
  );
  return{
    statusCode: 200
    
  }
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      statusCode: 400,
      error: error.message,
    };
  }
};
```